# getting data from a table using store procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I have a table named 
CUSTOMERANSWER table -(customeranswerID(pk),customerID(fk), surveyID(fk), question(fk), Answer, answereddate)

I'm trying to fetch the data by specific surveyID with the questionid should be equal to the no. of questions in the question's table.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `prc_feedbackAnswers`(IN `inputsurveyID` INT(11))
BEGIN
DECLARE _questionID INT;
DECLARE _questioncount INT;
SET _questionID = 1;
SET _questioncount = (SELECT count(questionID) From QUESTIONOPTION Where surveyID = inputsurveyID);
WHILE (_questionID <=(_questioncount+1))
DO
SELECT surveyID, questionID, answer
FROM CUSTOMERANSWER
WHERE surveyID = inputsurveyID AND questionID = _questionID;
SET _questionID = _questionID + 1;
END WHILE;
END
```

the output i got is

[image]

what i want is in one table. here its given the surveyID, questionId, answer each time.

please help.

Comment: Don't use the while loop inside your procedure. It should return single set of result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
WHILE (_questionID <=(_questioncount+1))
DO
    SELECT surveyID, questionID, answer
    FROM CUSTOMERANSWER
    WHERE surveyID = inputsurveyID AND questionID = _questionID;
    SET _questionID = _questionID + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Try this:

```
 SELECT surveyID, questionID, answer
 FROM CUSTOMERANSWER
 WHERE surveyID = inputsurveyID
 ORDER BY questionID
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but you might want something along these lines

```
SELECT surveyID, questionID, answer
FROM CUSTOMERANSWER
join  (
    SELECT inputsurveyID, count(questionID) as Q
    From QUESTIONOPTION 
    Where surveyID = inputsurveyID -- (not required, might be more efficient)
    group by inputsurveyID
) as N
on surveyID = inputsurveyID 
and questionID = Q
```